# Get list data api using angular4

Tags: angular, angular-http

I am in problem with get api, here is `student_name` in api student. Here is my code I tried

Api 
`{
"error": null,
"result": 
[{"id": 1, "student_name": "Alex" }, {"id":2, "student_name": "Bob"}]
}`

Typescript: `student.service.ts`

```
listStudent(){
    return this.http.get('api/student')
      .map(HttpHandle.extractData.bind(null, 'list student'))
      .catch(HttpHandle.handleError)
  }
```

extractDate method in http-handle.ts:

```
public static extractData(name: string, res: Response): Observable<Response> {
    if (res.status < 300) {
      console.log(`%c# Response status ${res.status}, ${name}, ${res.arrayBuffer().byteLength} bytes`,
        'color: #00CC00; font-weight:bold;');

      if (printDetail) {
        console.groupCollapsed('\tResponse');
        console.log(`${JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}`);
        console.groupEnd();
      }
    }
    else {
      console.log(`%c# Response status ${res.status}, ${name}, ${res.arrayBuffer().byteLength} bytes`,
        'color: #CC0000; font-weight:bold;');
      console.groupCollapsed('\tResponse');
      console.log(`${JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)}`);
      console.groupEnd();
    }

    return res.json();
  }
```

My Component: `student.component.ts`

```
export class StudentComponent{
lstStudent: string[];// I think something went wrong
public student_name: string;
....
constructor(
  private studentService: StudentService,
  ) { }
....
getStudents(){
    this.studentService.listStudent()
      .subscribe(data =>{
        this.lstStudent = data['lstStudent'];
        this.student_name = this.lstStudent...;//This is my issue 
      }
  );
  }
```

Html

```
<select class="form-control" title="list Student"
                 [(ngModel)]="lstStudent" name="lstStudent">
 <option *ngFor="let x of lstStudent" [ngValue]="x.student_name">{{x.student_name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

So how to get `student_name` and use it for HTML in `select` tag.
Thank you.

Comment: Your `json` object is incorrect it should be array `[{"id": 1, "student_name": "Alex" }, {"id":2, "student_name": "Bob"}]` for iterate in `ngFor`.

Comment: ok, thanks, but that is my typo mistake. I updated.

Comment: What is `this.lstStudent`?

Comment: I declare it is a array as above, but l think it's incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

In your component typescript file:

```
private selectedStudentId:number;

this.studentService.listStuden().subscribe(data => {
               this.lstStudents = data['result'];
               this.selectedStudentId = this.lstStudents[0].id;
});
```

and in your html file:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedStudent">
    <option *ngFor="let student of lstStudents" value="{{student.id}}">
            {{student.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues in your code

```
1. in your student.component.ts declare lstStudent like below

    lstStudent: any[];// change it to any[]

2.  subscribe to the Observable like below in the getStudents() method

    this.studentService.listStudent()
    .subscribe(data =>{
    this.lstStudent = data.result;
      }
    );
  }

3. in your HTML, change the ngModel name to something like "StudentList" to avoid confusion with the lstStudent variable returned from service. You can get selected value from this ngModel name. I have used [value] property binding here.

<select class="form-control" title="list Student"
                 [(ngModel)]="StudentList" name="StudentList">
 <option *ngFor="let x of lstStudent" [value]="x.student_name">{{x.student_name}}
 </option>
</select>
```

let me know if it works. Also can you post it your code for the 
**extractData** method in your service as used below

`.map(HttpHandle.extractData.bind(null, 'list student'))`

Comment: thank you. Maybe something went wrong, it doesn't work, error is "Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]'. I updated extractData method.

Comment: i changed the code in listStudent() method as below .
`this.lstStudent = data.result;`
Can you  post the value of `res.json()` in extractData method after logging in console.